# API Workbench doesn't see git

Tags: windows, git, atom-editor

I am using Atom with [API Workbench](http://apiworkbench.com/) installed on Windows.

I go by `Packages -> API Workbench -> Get APIs from -> Popular APIs (Community)`.
Atom responds by displaying `GIT is required to clone APIs. Please instal GIT.`.

I do have git installed. Typing `git --version` in `cmd` gives `git version 2.6.3.windows.1`.

What do I need to do to be able to clone APIs using API Workbench?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm running across the same problem